# How to pass input to a java program through command prompt which is an xml string with multiple lines and contains special characters

Tags: java

I want to  send input to  a java program through command prompt which is an xml string with multiple lines and contains special characters. When I am directly pasting the string after the command javac filename "xml string" each new line is executing differently and the result is error how can i do it. Please help on this

Comment: in linux just pipe your XML to your program, and in your program get hold of System.in input stream from which you can read the whole thing. In modern windows, use Powershell to achieve the same: `C:\>PowerShell -Command "$xml | java my-program"`

Comment: actually I am windows user I cannot pass it through power shell due to some limitation I have to definitely make it through command prompt only.

Comment: Save it to file and pass the file name as a parameter to your program

Comment: work soft is a testing tool which runs soap ui internally through  process executor this tool is giving input to sopa ui only through  process executor like we give input to java through command prompt  ie i have an option only to give input i dont have any option to give file this is the problem I am having.

Comment: I need some help like putting entire xml between some special character  which will make windows to accept entire string at once